# How to distribute modules with python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I've seen on [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/) that distutils is "legacy" since Python 3.4. What is now the recommended (or standard) way to distribute packages and/or modules.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the documentation for the [`distutils`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html#module-distutils) module says it all:

> The `distutils` package provides support for building and installing
>   additional modules into a Python installation. The new modules may be
>   either 100%-pure Python, or may be extension modules written in C, or
>   may be collections of Python packages which include modules coded in
>   both Python and C.
>
> Most Python users will not want to use this module directly, but
>   **instead use the cross-version tools maintained by the Python Packaging
>   Authority. Refer to the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) for more
>   information.**
>
> For the benefits of packaging tool authors and users seeking a deeper
>   understanding of the details of the current packaging and distribution
>   system, the legacy distutils based user documentation and API
>   reference remain available:
>
> - [Installing Python Modules (Legacy version)](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#install-index)
> - [Distributing Python Modules (Legacy version)](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/index.html#distutils-index)

In particular inside the [linked user guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/current.html#packaging-tool-recommendations) they state:

> - Use [`setuptools`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/projects.html#setuptools) to define projects and create Source Distributions. [5] [6]
> - Use the `bdist_wheel` `setuptools` extension available from the wheel project to create wheels. This is especially beneficial, if your
>     project contains binary extensions. [7]
> - Use `twine` for uploading distributions to PyPI.

And later on:

> `distribute` was a fork of `setuptools` that was merged back into
>   setuptools (in v0.7), thereby making **setuptools the primary choice for
>   Python packaging.**

---

In other words:

- `distutils` is **still** the standard way. Only, it's more low level than what most people want. It's the foundantion on top of which the other tools are built, so it is *not* "legacy". In fact there is *no mention of deprecation* in the docs.
- `setuptools` is the *preferred* way to distribute a package.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/current.html) it is recommended to use [setuptools](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/projects.html#setuptools) and then [twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine) to create PyPi packages.